# Are Python's decimal module calculations actually done with integers?

Tags: python-3.x, int, decimal

I'm using Python3's [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) module.  Is the underlying arithmetic done using the processors floating point types, or does it use integers?  The notion that the results are 'exact' and of arbitrary precision suggests to me that integer maths is used below the surface.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is integer math, not float math for sure. Roughly speaking every float is two parts - before and after the decimal dot (integer and the remainder). Thanks to that the calculations are done using integer arithmetic and hence are not rounded up so they are staying precise even if you sum up a very large value with a very small fraction.

This comes at a price - the number of operations is significantly larger and it is not always necessary to be so precise at all times. That is why most of the calculations are done using float arithmetic that may cause a loss of precision when there are many arithmetic operations on floats or there are significant differences between the values (e.g. 10^10 ratio and more). There is a separate field of computer science: [numerical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) or numerical methods that study the clever ways to get the most of the speed of float calculations while maintaining highest precision possible.